# Tikz for drawing box flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, box

how can I draw something like this in Latex? I couldn't find anything in tikz examples....
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 6):

As [Stefan Pinnow pointed out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471347/tikz-for-drawing-box-flowchart#comment1187700_471347), the purpose of this site is not to convert screen shots into LaTeX code. However, for newcomers sometimes exceptions are made. I hope that this gives you enough motivation to look up these things in the manual and/or examples on this and other sites.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,shadows,chains,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={on chain,join,draw,minimum width=7cm,minimum height=1cm,
align=center},start chain=going below,every join/.append style={-latex},
node distance=5mm,font=\sffamily,fbox/.style={draw,thick,fill=white,drop shadow}]
  \node[box] (a) {Alignment};
  \node[box] (b) {Tracking};
  \node[box] (c) {Classification};
  \node[above=3mm of a.north west,xshift=3mm] (l) {Fusion};
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
   \node[fbox,fit=(a|-l.north) (c),inner xsep=3mm] (f1){};
  \end{scope}
  \node[above=1.5cm of f1.north west,anchor=west,minimum width=2.5cm,minimum
  height=1cm,fbox] (1) {Sensor 1};
  \node[above=1.5cm of f1.north east,anchor=east,minimum width=2.5cm,minimum
  height=1cm,fbox] (N) {Sensor $N$};
  \draw[dashed,ultra thick,shorten >=2mm,shorten <=2mm] (1) -- (N);
  \foreach \X in {1,N}
  {\draw[-latex] (\X) -- (f1.north-|\X.center) node[fill=white,pos=0.5]{Raw Data};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]